# Использование 128 аппаратных потоков в C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, многопоточность, winapi

Работаю в Microsoft Visual Studio 2019, ОС Windows 10 Professional. Процессор имеет 64/128 ядер/потоков.

Пишу:

```
const auto N = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
```

В результате N равно 64. В диспетчере устройств, AIDA и др. отображается 128 логических процессоров.

Как задействовать 128 потоков? Подозреваю, что Windows объединяет исполнителей в процессорные группы по 64, поэтому для одного приложения "стандартно" доступно только 64. Допускается решение с применением WinAPI.

Comment: просто создать эти 128 потоков. значение, возвращаемое hardware_concurrency, никак не ограничивает число создаваемых потоков

Comment: @user7860670 а будет ли задействовано именно 128 аппаратных потоков? И как повлиять на значение от hardware_concurrency?

Comment: А какой именно процессор? Наличие 128 ядер не означает возможность одновременного эффективного запуска 128  потоков (и наоборот). У меня, например, 16 ядер, но 8 64-разрядных АЛУ (и еще 8 32-разрядных), hardware_concurrency() выдает 8. В зависимости от задач эффективность распараллеливания меняется, но бывает, что масштабирование линейно до 16 потоков. При Hyper-Threading наоборот, hardware_concurrency возвращает количество физических ядер, но на одном ядре может эффективно выполняться несколько параллельных потоков (за счет конвейризации)

Comment: а что вообще значит, что процессор имеет 128 потоков? возможно речь о логических ядрах?

Comment: будут ли они задействоваться или нет - это уж как операционная система решит. если ничего другого не запущено - то навярняка будут

Comment: @Ariox процессор AMD Ryzen Threadripper 3990X

Comment: Я в курсе, как работает Hyper Threading и SMT на аппаратном уровне, но я видел бенчмарк-тесты для этого процессора с задействованием 128 потоков. Там, конечно, прирост производительности нелинейный из-за многих факторов, но экстремум (точка насыщения) на 128.

Comment: Комментаторы! Вопрос не о том, как запустить потоки, а о том, как получить правильное количество логических ядер.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31362324/5045688 - вызов `cpuinfo` какой результат даёт?